# Preprocessing an image dataset including division into training and test sets

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I am learning multiimage classification with deep learning models. I am using Keras and Tensorflow for the classification task.

The image dataset (10,000 images) is an array and the labels are in a csv file containing image names and gold labels with 10 classes. I am retrieving the images and labels with the following code:

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   path = '/content/image_data/'
   all_images = np.load(path + 'all_images.npy')
   crowd_annotations = pd.read_csv(path + 'crowd_annotationsGold.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
   crowd_annotations = crowd_annotations['label'].to_numpy()

   print(all_images )
   print(crowd_annotations)
```

When I print, I get the following array data:

```
          [[[[0.23137255 0.24313725 0.24705882]
             [0.16862745 0.18039216 0.17647059]
             [0.19607843 0.18823529 0.16862745]
              ...
             [0.61960784 0.51764706 0.42352941]
             [0.59607843 0.49019608 0.4       ]
             [0.58039216 0.48627451 0.40392157]]

            [[0.0627451  0.07843137 0.07843137]
             [0.         0.         0.        ]
             [0.07058824 0.03137255 0.        ]
              ...
             [0.48235294 0.34509804 0.21568627]
             [0.46666667 0.3254902  0.19607843]
             [0.47843137 0.34117647 0.22352941]]

            [[0.09803922 0.09411765 0.08235294]
             [0.0627451  0.02745098 0.        ]
             [0.19215686 0.10588235 0.03137255]
              ...
             [0.4627451  0.32941176 0.19607843]
             [0.47058824 0.32941176 0.19607843]
             [0.42745098 0.28627451 0.16470588]]

             ......

            [[0.69411765 0.56470588 0.45490196]
             [0.65882353 0.50588235 0.36862745]
             [0.70196078 0.55686275 0.34117647]
              .....
             [0.84705882 0.72156863 0.54901961]
             [0.59215686 0.4627451  0.32941176]
             [0.48235294 0.36078431 0.28235300]]]

           [[[0.60392157 0.69411765 0.73333333]
             [0.49411765 0.5372549  0.53333333]
             [0.41176471 0.40784314 0.37254902]
              .....
             [0.35686275 0.37254902 0.27843737]
             [0.34117647 0.35294118 0.27843137]
             [0.30980392 0.31764706 0.2745098 ]]

            [[0.54901961 0.62745098 0.6627451 ]
             [0.56862745 0.6        0.60392157]
             [0.49019608 0.49019608 0.4627451 ]
              ...
             [0.37647059 0.38823529 0.30588235]
             [0.30196078 0.31372549 0.24313725]
             [0.27843137 0.28627451 0.23921569]]

            [[0.54901961 0.60784314 0.64313725]
             [0.54509804 0.57254902 0.58431373]
             [0.45098039 0.45098039 0.43921569]
              ...
             [0.30980392 0.32156863 0.25098039]
             [0.26666667 0.2745098  0.21568627]
             [0.2627451  0.27058824 0.21568627]]

             .......

           [[0.58823529 0.56078431 0.52941176]
            [0.54901961 0.52941176 0.49803922]
            [0.51764706 0.49803922 0.47058824]
             ...
            [0.87843137 0.87058824 0.85490196]
            [0.90196078 0.89411765 0.88235294]
            [0.94509804 0.94509804 0.93333333]]

           [[0.5372549  0.51764706 0.49411765]
            [0.50980392 0.49803922 0.47058824]
            [0.49019608 0.4745098  0.45098039]
             ...
            [0.70980392 0.70588235 0.69803922]
            [0.79215686 0.78823529 0.77647059]
            [0.83137255 0.82745098 0.81176471]]

           [[0.47843137 0.46666667 0.44705882]
            [0.4627451  0.45490196 0.43137255]
            [0.47058824 0.45490196 0.43529412]
             ...
            [0.70196078 0.69411765 0.67843137]
            [0.64313725 0.64313725 0.63529412]
            [0.63921569 0.63921569 0.63137255]]]]

            [0 0 0 ... 9 9 9]
```

I want to divide the data into training and test sets.

After division, I want an array of the training data and another array of the test data and both saved separately. Similarly, a list or csv file of the train labels and one list or csv file for the test labels. As the data is in sorted order so a shuffle might be required before dividing them into train and test sets.

After that i want to use them for training the models and then evaluation. The size of test set should be 20 percent.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html. Does this help?

Comment: I know scikit-learn's train_test_split method but it does not full fill my requirements. I have to save the files separately and it is not possible with these methods.

Comment: So once you have done the split using the train_test_split function you can save them into separate files, right? If this doesn't help can you please elaborate your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [StratifiedShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html), which returns the indices of the training and test sets in stratified manner (*which also ensures a good distribution/representation of the classes in both sets*).

Once you have the indices, you just need to slice your data, then save them the way you wish.

---

Below is a simple example, for illustration:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

SEED = 2020  # for reproducibility due to the shuffling

# create some random classification data - make it small for printing out
X, Y = make_classification(n_samples=20, n_features=3, n_informative=3,
                           n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, n_clusters_per_class=1,
                           n_classes=3, random_state=SEED)

print("X Original: \n{}\n".format(X))
print("Y Original: \n{}\n".format(Y))

# perform stratified shuffle split. Note the SEED usage for shuffling.
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.3, random_state=SEED)
train_index, test_index = next(sss.split(X, Y))
X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

print("X_Train: \n{}\n".format(X_train))
print("Y_Train: \n{}\n".format(Y_train))
print("X_Test: \n{}\n".format(X_test))
print("Y_Test: \n{}\n".format(Y_test))

# your code for saving X_train and X_test in separate NPY files, goes here
# your code for saving Y_train and Y_test in separate CSV files, goes here
```

### Output

```
X Original: 
[[-0.69590064 -0.67561329  0.62524618]
 [-1.09492175  1.27630932  2.15598887]
 [-0.51743065  0.63402055  2.12912755]
 [-1.18819319 -0.42454412  1.49949316]
 [-2.09612492  0.89610929 -0.34134785]
 [ 1.06615086 -2.74141467 -0.26813435]
 [-0.88205757  0.84812284 -0.65742989]
 [-0.95747896 -1.70466278  0.69822828]
 [-0.15885567 -0.15289292 -1.00694331]
 [-0.93374229 -0.79402593  1.00909515]
 [-0.90636868  2.75448909  1.772864  ]
 [ 0.62005229 -1.3732454  -0.39237323]
 [ 0.74139934 -1.05271986 -0.9964703 ]
 [-1.81968206  1.53213677 -0.94698653]
 [-0.43419928  0.90834502  2.05707125]
 [-0.19206677  0.3104947   0.11505178]
 [-0.19129044 -0.39785095 -0.13277081]
 [-1.64958117  1.57707358  0.67063495]
 [-1.27544266 -1.26647034  1.3965837 ]
 [ 1.63351975 -0.85734405 -1.52143762]]

Y Original: 
[1 0 0 1 0 2 2 1 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 1 2]

X_Train: 
[[-0.51743065  0.63402055  2.12912755]
 [ 1.63351975 -0.85734405 -1.52143762]
 [-0.93374229 -0.79402593  1.00909515]
 [ 0.74139934 -1.05271986 -0.9964703 ]
 [ 1.06615086 -2.74141467 -0.26813435]
 [-2.09612492  0.89610929 -0.34134785]
 [-1.27544266 -1.26647034  1.3965837 ]
 [-0.15885567 -0.15289292 -1.00694331]
 [-0.19206677  0.3104947   0.11505178]
 [-0.43419928  0.90834502  2.05707125]
 [-1.64958117  1.57707358  0.67063495]
 [-1.18819319 -0.42454412  1.49949316]
 [-0.95747896 -1.70466278  0.69822828]
 [-1.81968206  1.53213677 -0.94698653]]

Y_Train: 
[0 2 1 2 2 0 1 2 1 0 0 1 1 0]

X_Test: 
[[-0.88205757  0.84812284 -0.65742989]
 [-0.90636868  2.75448909  1.772864  ]
 [-0.69590064 -0.67561329  0.62524618]
 [ 0.62005229 -1.3732454  -0.39237323]
 [-0.19129044 -0.39785095 -0.13277081]
 [-1.09492175  1.27630932  2.15598887]]

Y_Test: 
[2 0 1 2 1 0]
```

### UPDATE

Based on your comment below, if you want to reconstruct the same `CSV` file from a `DataFrame` with the existing columns (i.e. in addition to `label` which is unusual). You can still slice the original pandas `DataFrame` `crowd_annotations` as follows:

First, load the `CSV` file into `crowd_annotations_` (mind the underscore):

```
crowd_annotations_ = pd.read_csv(path + 'crowd_annotationsGold.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Then obtain `label` separately:

```
crowd_annotations = crowd_annotations_['label'].to_numpy()
```

Continue as in the example provided above, by splitting `all_images` `crowd_annotations`, which correspond to `X` and `Y`, respectively.

Finally, use `train_index` and `test_index` in both `crowd_annotations` (as in above example), and `crowd_annotations_` as follows:

```
crowd_annotations_train = crowd_annotations_.iloc[train_index]
crowd_annotations_test = crowd_annotations_.iloc[test_index]
# save crowd_annotations_train and crowd_annotations_test as `CSV`
```

Comment: Dear@Yahya. Thanks alot for the answer. One thing is still not clear. The original csv file for annotations has an index either as image name or simply a number to track the record of each image and its individual annotations and gold label. But it was not the case with image data as array because there are no image names. So when the data is shuffled during the split, the old indices are not anymore synchronized. After division, i wanted to keep that old index of the annotation data with train and test splits so that array indices and gold label indices are still synchronized.

Comment: If i understood properly lets say i got this new array as: crowd_annotationsIDX = crowd_annotations['ID'].to_numpy(). suppose its Y1, so train_index, test_index, y1_index = next(sss.split(X, Y, Y1)) right ? Then saving it with X_train, X_test and Y_train and Y_test.

Comment: @codeDB I will update my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks a lot brother @Yahya for taking so much time for a person you don't know. God bless you...

Comment: Yes! It is due to sharing the same faith and the importance of your name :). These few words of appreciation are the only thing i can do for in return.

Comment: @codeDB Glad to hear that. Wish you all the best brother.